# Having trouble with the .send() method of WebSocket in Spring Boot Project

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to make a live poker application using Java Spring Boot Framework. I'm using WebSocket for full-duplex comms between players at the table. Right now I'm trying to make a player-icon show up for all users when a user takes a seat at the table. However, I'm having trouble with my WebSocket Controller -- it doesn't seem to be connecting at all to the front end stompClient.send() method that I'm calling. I know that the front end is sending the message correctly, as the logs on the browser say as much. This the JS code I'm using to send information about the player and the seat at the table they have taken:

```
stompClient.send("app/addUser",
        {},
        JSON.stringify({
            seat: seat,
            player: player
        })
    );
```

... and this is what my controller looks like:

```
@Controller
public class TableWebSocketController {
    @MessageMapping("/app/addUser")
    @SendTo("topic/seated-players")
    public CreatePlayerRequest addUser(@Payload CreatePlayerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        return request;
    }
}
```

As of right now, the "Test" message will not show up in my IDE console, nor will the subsequent code in "topic/seated-players". Here's CreatePlayerRequest, in case that will come in handy:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CreatePlayerRequest {
    private Player player;
    private int seat;
}
```

I'm not getting errors messages anywhere, so I'm really stumped on this one. Any idea on what could be wrong? Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

I simply want the Controller to return the CreatePlayerRequest to "topic/seated-players", and then eventually create a player-icon for all users to subscribed to that topic to see. I really just need to figure out why my controller is not working.